# jQuery autocomplete with keyword search?

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

Is there any posibility to avoid people to search type keyword and press enter button rather than selecting autofilter value.

Because i have created autocomplete search box where if a peoples type any word which doesntt give auto complte results , but if a user press enter it gives resuts.. i want to limit the search only for with autofilter values .

Comment: @Ideal Bakija : added the code . but not working . kindly please advice

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="name" name="name" autocomplete="off">
```

If you don't want to show autocomplete just turn it off in the input!

and if you want to know it the keypress is enter

do this.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.input-class', funciton(e){

if (e.keyCode == 13) {
code  here
}


});
```

the key code 13 will check is the user pressed enter when he was writing. Is yes then it will proceess it .. Hope this helps you now!

Comment: no i want other way . i dont want a results of keyword search on autocomplete search box .

Comment: what do you want excaclty... this is not going to give you results on autocomplete ... it is going to disable it

Comment: :Ex: i want to search hotels and autofilter gives resutl for "hotel" instead of hotels . so im not select "hotel" from autofilter . i just type it on search box and enter .. how to avoid such search

Comment: On the text that you print on autocomplete print for ex. "input-class" on it and that will call the function that I wrote above. This function should be independent and not inside the function you print your autocomplete!